# Unable to access isNetworkSupported in android ConnectivityManager class

Tags: android

I am trying use `isNetworkSupported(int networkType)` to check hardware is support wifi only mode. But it giving error like "The method isNetworkSupported(int) is undefined for the type ConnectivityManager

Following is my code:

```
 ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
 boolean checkStatus =  cm.isNetworkSupported(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
```

Please tell me how we can access this `isNetworkSupported` method inside our activity.

Thanks.

Comment: can you paste the code with details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys!

After some research and with my colleagues helps I used java reflections to solve this issue 
like below.

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)
this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

final Class<?> cmlClass = cm.getClass();
String status = "";
try { 

    final Method wifiCheckMethod = cmlClass.getMethod("isNetworkSupported", int.class);
    boolean hasMobileNetwork = (Boolean) wifiCheckMethod.invoke(cm, ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
    status = hasMobileNetwork ? "This device has mobile support model" : "This is wifi only model";
    Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "The network status is..."+hasMobileNetwork);

} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    status = "Error while getting device support model";
}

Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Network support message.."+status, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 2):

As per the [`document`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html), `isNetworkSupported` is not the method for the class `ConnectivityManager`.

if you want check internet connection status check this

```
ConnectivityManager cm =
    (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
                  activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
```

But I am able to see this method in  https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/android-4.3_r2.1/core/java/android/net/ConnectivityManager.java  and in android studio also it is showing this method.